Autodesk derivative metadata big files
I´m using Autodesk derivative to convert to SVF2. After that, I need to download the metadata, all the properties, but for specific files like NWD files the metadata file is very big, so could be 500 or 800 MB.
In the documentation of derivative APIs there are some limitations: is not possible to download the metadata file if is bigger than 800 MB. The other option is to download each properties one by one, but for me is not a good solution.

Is there any possibility to download by chunk? I tried to specify the bytes range in the header but it was ignored.
Can we use webhook to get when the job of getting the metadata has finished or the only way is to do requests every X seconds to know if the metadata is ready to be download?
Is there any way to get the metadata file size before trying to download, to know what to do before getting the http error?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
